# How to automatically start the perfmon on SQL Server cluster active node

Tags: sql-server, perfmon

How can we start running perfmon automatically on active SQL Server active node?  Typically when we failover to the inactive node and we forgot to run the perfmon.  We want to start running the perfmom automatically if possible.  If not how can we tell if perfmon is not running so we can send out alert to start the perfmom?  We can watch the log file output but we want to know if there is more elegance solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is to schedule a SQL Agent job at agent startup to start the perfmon counter on the node using logman.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/nt_command_logman.mspx?mfr=true